# Rails: Why can't my object created by ajax be used to trigger javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement an ajax voting system for a model "Things", where if a user votes on  Thing then a new Thing appears in the old one's place, which he can then vote on, and so on. This takes place on the Thing view itself.

I'm pretty sure this exact code was working a week ago, but now it mysteriously broke. Now, the Thing is replaced upon the first vote, but after that, voting no longer brings forth a new Thing:

**views/things/show.html.erb**

```
<div id="randajax">
  <%= link_to image_tag("UpArrowGray.jpg", class: "rand_up_vote"), upvoterandom_thing_path(@rand.id), remote: true, method: :get %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function reload_script() {
        $(".rand_up_vote").click(function () {
          $.get( "<%= upvoterandom_thing_path(:id => @rand.id) %>", function( data ) {
            $('#randajax').html(data);
            reload_script();
          });
        });
    }
    reload_script();
  </script>
</div>
```

**controllers/things_controller.rb**

```
def upvoterandom
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  UpVote.create!
  @rand = Thing.all.first
  render text: "<a data-method=\'get\' data-remote=\'true\' href=\'" + upvoterandom_thing_path(@rand.id) + "\'><img alt=\'Upvote\' class=\'rand_upp_vote\' src=\'/assets/UpArrowGray.jpg\' /></a>".html_safe
end
```

Apparently the issue is that an item created with ajax can't execute javascript. The web console shows that the `upvoterandom_thing_path` is getting executed, but nothing happens to the `randajax div`. I tried giving the Thing created from the original javascript a differenc class with different javascript and that didn't work either, although a seperate item ("THIS_WORKS") with the same class executed the same javascript normally:

**views/things/show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "THIS_WORKS", "#", class: "TEST_TEST", remote: true %>

<div id="randajax">
  <%= link_to image_tag("UpArrowGray.jpg", class: "rand_up_vote"), upvoterandom_thing_path(@rand.id), remote: true, method: :get %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function reload_script() {
        $(".rand_up_vote").click(function () {
          $.get( "<%= upvoterandom_thing_path(:id => @rand.id) %>", function( data ) {
            $('#randajax').html(data);
            reload_script();
          });
        });
    }
    reload_script();
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".TEST_TEST").click(function () {
      $('#randajax').html("TEST");
      });
  </script> 
</div>
```

**controllers/things_controller.rb**

```
def upvoterandom
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  UpVote.create!
  @rand = Thing.all.first
  render text: "<a data-method=\'get\' data-remote=\'true\' href=\'" + upvoterandom_thing_path(@rand.id) + "\'><img alt=\'Upvote\' class=\'rand_up_vote\' src=\'/assets/UpArrowGray.jpg\' /></a>".html_safe
end
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening or how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set it up, you do this in your javascript:

```
$(".rand_up_vote").click(function () {
  ...
```

This sets up the click event on the elements.  When one of the elements is replaced, or a new one is added, it hasn't had this event added to it, so it won't work like the others.

To fix this, you need to add this same event to the new element, OR remove the event from all elements and then add it to all elements (if you don't remove it first you risk firing the same event twice on a click or whatever).

EDIT with a proposed solution.

The simplest way is to add an onclick attribute to your elements, to run the reload_script() function.  Change this so that it doesn't add an onclick to the events. I was about to start editing your code and i noticed that the `reload_script` function calls itself at the end of the anonymous function you're adding as the onclick event:  this means that when you click on a .rand_up_vote element, it will do the AJAX get, replace the html, and then add another onclick to all the elements.  This is definitely not right - was this an earlier attempt to fix this problem?

You probably just need something like this:

```
<div id="randajax">
  <%= link_to image_tag("UpArrowGray.jpg", class: "rand_up_vote"), upvoterandom_thing_path(@rand.id), remote: true, method: :get %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function reload_script() {
      $.get( "<%= upvoterandom_thing_path(:id => @rand.id) %>", function( data ) {
        $('#randajax').html(data);
      });
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

now edit the html so that each .rand_up_vote element has an `onclick="reload_script()"` attribute.

Comment: How would I add it to the new element? I thought the javascript existed on it's own as opposed to 'belonging' to something.

Comment: When you say `$(".rand_up_vote").click(function ` you AREN'T saying "whenever anyone clicks on .rand_up_vote, run this code", although you could be forgiven for thinking that.  You're saying "Add an onclick event to all of the .rand_up_vote elements that exist WHEN THIS BIT OF CODE RUNS", which is on pageload.  Think of it as a timeline.  The js runs on pageload and adds events to elements.  An element is replaced with a new element.  The new element missed the event-adding.

Comment: That's incredibly helpful, but I am still unclear on one thing: what is the syntax for adding a javascript attribute to an html element?

Comment: Depends on the event: any code you put on an element will need to be triggered by a specific event happening on that element - click, mouseDown, keyUp, etc.  To add some code to the click event, say `onclick="alert("hello")"`.